# create element and then insert html tag

Tags: javascript

I have a json data and I'm looping inside of it and create a set of li's in every (.searchinput-sub)

```
var searchinput_sub = document.querySelectorAll(".searchinput-sub");
for (var i = 0, max = searchinput_sub.length; i < max; i++) {
    var jsonResData = JSON.parse(e.data);
    for(var l=0;l<jsonResData.length;l++){
        //create a li element
        var newEl = document.createElement('li');
        newEl.innerHtml ='<a href="#">test</a>';
        searchinput_sub[i].querySelector('.resultsHolder').appendChild(newEl);
    }
}
```

but this part

```
newEl.innerHtml ='<a href="#">test</a>';
```

is not working, like only li tags was added. Any ideas, help please?

Comment: you have misspelled innerHTML. HTML of innerHTML should be in caps.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is just a minor issue

Answer (score 4):

It will be  `innerHTML` not `innerHtml`:

```
newEl.innerHTML ='<a href="#">test</a>';
```